What is the numeric version number of Android 12L?
Wikipedia has:

Android 12.1/12L
In October 2021, Google announced Android 12L, an interim release of Android 12 including improvements specific for foldable phones, tablets, desktop-sized screens and Chromebooks, and modifications to the user interface to tailor it to larger screens. It was planned to launch in early 2022. Developer Preview 1 of Android 12L was released in October 2021, followed by Beta 1 in December 2021, Beta 2 in January 2022, and Beta 3 in February 2022. The stable version of Android 12L was released for devices with large screens on March 7, 2022, and was released as "Android 12.1" for Pixel smartphones on the same date, besides the Pixel 6 & Pixel 6 Pro.

I've been gathering some statistics on the decline in use of older Android versions over time, using Statcounter Global Stats. You can get a lot more information than the line charts without a Premium account, by downloading the .csv files and doing a bit of spreadsheet processing on them.
The surprising thing is that none of the stats show me any presence of Android 12.1, which is supposed to be the version number of 12L. I can see small numbers of Android 12.2, and plenty of 12.0, but no 12.1, 12.3 or higher. Statcounter gets its information from the browser user-agent strings. From their FAQ:

Statcounter is a web analytics service. Our tracking code is installed on more than 1.5 million sites globally. These sites cover various activities and geographic locations. Every month, we record billions of page views to these sites. For each page view, we analyse the browser/operating system/screen resolution used and we establish if the page view is from a mobile device.

The least-used versions from the July 2024 stats are:
4.4 KitKat              0.17%
24.6                    0.06%
4.1 Jelly Bean          0.06%
4.3 Jelly Bean          0.03%
2.2 Froyo               0.02%
12.2                    0.02%
15                      0.01%
4.2 Jelly Bean          0.01%
4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich  0.01%
Other                   0.05%

Possible explanations include:

12L gets reported as 12.2.
12L is so little used that it's lost in rounding to the nearest 0.1% and "12.2" is something else. There doesn't seem to have been a CynogenMod 12.1.

I'd also be interested to know what "24.6" might be, but that's not the point of this question.

Looking at my user agent string of Chrome on Android 14 I don't see any Android version related component. And on my Android 13 device the user agent contains 10 as Android version. Therefore I wouldn't rely too much on those numbers.

Android 12L is Android 12.1.0. However, in general, it's branded as Android 12.
The official Android Developers site for "Get 12L" links to Android Flash Tool with 12.1.0 prefilled.
Also, browsing the list of Factory Images for Nexus and Pixel Devices, version 12.1.0 is included on supported devices (Pixel 3a to Pixel 6a).
While there's an "API diffs - API 31 → API 32" on the left menu, apparently Android 12L is still considered API 31. From the official distributions of Android versions (JSON, download only),
  {
    "name": "S",
    "version": "12",
    "apiLevel": 31,
    ...
    "url": "https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12",
    "descriptionBlocks": [
      ...
      {
        "title": "Large screen support (12L)",
        "body": "System UI optimizations App taskbar Drag and drop an app into split-screen mode fast app-switching Visual and stability improvements to compatibility mode Activity embedding with Jetpack WindowManager"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "T",
    "version": "13",
    "apiLevel": 33,
    ...
    "url": "https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13",
    "descriptionBlocks": [
        ...
    ]
  },

As for the user-agent, it might not be the most reliable info to indicate the precise Android version due to privacy and spoofing. On Pixel 3a running Android 12L:

Firefox 128 shows "Android 12" with an empty model.
Chrome 110, Edge 126, Opera 83, Brave 1.68 fixed the Android version to Android 10 on model K.

